# R: What is the type of `...`?

Tags: r, types, parameter-passing

```
> typeof(...)
Error: '...' used in an incorrect context
```

Does ... have no type? I thought everything in R has a type.
So I ran some tests.

```
> is.function(...)
Error: '...' used in an incorrect context
> is.call(...)
Error: '...' used in an incorrect context
> is.function(...)
Error: '...' used in an incorrect context
> is.call(...)
Error: '...' used in an incorrect context
> is.name(...)
Error: '...' used in an incorrect context
> is.pairlist(...)
Error: '...' used in an incorrect context
> is.list(...)
Error: '...' used in an incorrect context
> is.expression(...)
Error: '...' used in an incorrect context
> is.language(...)
Error: '...' used in an incorrect context
```

I thought I learned something from

```
> typeof(quote(…))
[1] "symbol"
```

but

```
> typeof(quote(rumpelstiltskin))
[1] "symbol"
```

Comment: `...` is of type `...`. It is one of the basic types in R. see R language definition: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Dot_002ddot_002ddot.

Comment: I don't think that `...` has any real semantic meaning outside of a function that uses it as an argument. And even then, I think of it more like a syntactic flag to R that additional arguments passed are to be gathered and stored (per the docs) in an internal pairlist. But that pairlist doesn't exist until you're actually in a function and arguments are passed to `...`.

Comment: So, imo, the question "what is the type of '...'?" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @joran, I am not very happy with the answer of mt1022 , but I think it is an answer, so the question has an answer. Let me say what motivates it. There is a construction, f(a = b, c = 2) that you see in many places, including function definitions, function calls, as arguments passed to ...,  and in production of named lists. In some of these usages I see more expert R programmers refer to the LHS of the = as "tags." I've been trying to figure out which of these constructions create symbols, which create pairlists, in what environment, and so forth -- commonalities and differences in usage.

Comment: Well, my point was that I think you and mt1022 are misreading that section of the R Lang Def. `...` is "stored as a pairlist", but if you play around with actual functions you'll start to see that there isn't any `...` object without arguments passed to it. And the manual is saying that those arguments are collected and stored internally as a pairlist. So I read that as saying that `...` isn't a "thing", it's a label into which collections of things can be passed, and those collections become a pairlist.

Comment: @joran, aren't all named R objects merely labels in this sense? I suppose one could ask if it is a length-zero pairlist when nothing has been assigned to it.

Comment: I actually am sort of trying to suggest that it isn't really an object at all; it exists only at the level of the language parser as a token. In that `...` doesn't exists as a thing in R separate from the objects passed to it. `...` is literally just a token that the parser uses to interpret your code.